# Emacs warning after package updates

Tags: latex, auctex, warning, list-packages

After running updates using `list-packages`, emacs keeps popping out the following messages when I open a tex file. I tried to reinstall the packages and commented out all settings related to auctex, but the warning still shows up. What can I do to fix the issue?

```
Warning (auctex): `font-latex-update-font-lock' should not be called.
It is obsolete and going to be removed.
If you have called `font-latex-add-keywords' and want to refresh fontification,
call `font-lock-flush' instead.
If you changed syntactic fontification, e.g., one of the variables
- `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-environments'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local'
- `font-latex-syntactic-keywords-extra'
then call `font-latex-set-syntactic-keywords'.
Warning (auctex): `font-latex-update-font-lock' should not be called.
It is obsolete and going to be removed.
If you have called `font-latex-add-keywords' and want to refresh fontification,
call `font-lock-flush' instead.
If you changed syntactic fontification, e.g., one of the variables
- `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-environments'
- `LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local'
- `font-latex-syntactic-keywords-extra'
then call `font-latex-set-syntactic-keywords'.
```

Comment: There is a lisp file somewhere in you `load-path` which uses `font-latex-update-font-lock`.  Maybe an older AUCTeX installation?  Try `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` and check the results, maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. Like you said I have `auctex` packages installed with both ELPA and my os package manager, the latter has an older version.